# Split string based on the first occurring number javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a `string` which I want to split into *chunks* using the `.split()` function.

*Example strings*

```
59 Samuël 1 en 2 // Example 1
1 Saul omgekomen door het zwaard // Example 2
622 Koningen 1 tot 10 // Example 3
```

*Expected output*

```
['59', 'Samuël 1 en 2'] // Output example 1
['1', 'Saul omgekomen door het zwaard'] // Output example 2
['622', 'Koningen 1 tot 10'] // Output example 3
```

---

I tried the following code, based on anwsers found in other topics.

```js
var example_1 = '59 Samuël 1 en 2';
var example_2 = '1 Saul omgekomen door het zwaard';
var example_3 = '622 Koningen 1 tot 10';

console.log(example_1.split(/(\d+)/));
console.log(example_2.split(/(\d+)/));
console.log(example_3.split(/(\d+)/));
```

But the output is not the expected output, eg. `['59', 'Samuël 1 en 2']`

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: In this example you’d be better off splitting on the first whitespace character. Is this example exactly what you want to do or is there a scenario where the first whitespace might be incorrect?

Comment: @josh I think that might be actualy working. I didn't even think about that :)

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: @brk `['59', 'Samuël 1 en 2']`

Comment: Try console.dir( [string.substr(0, string.indexOf(" ")), string.substr(string.indexOf(" ") + 1)] );

Comment: What about -> `abc 59 Samuël 1 en 2`, does that want to be `['abc 59', 'Samuël 1 en 2']` or `['abc', '59', 'Samuël 1 en 2']`

Comment: @keith Well, that string never occurs. It always starts with a digit. `00 string`. But the string can contain digits, `00 string 0 and 0 and 1`.

Comment: In that case you could just do -> `"59 Samuël 1 en 2".match(/(\d\d) (.*)/).slice(1)`   This basically creates 2 capture groups, that I then slice of the first return as that's the original string, the rest are the capture groups your interested in.

Comment: @Keith For most strings this is indeed working, some of them return `null`. Im figuring out why that is. Can you write an awnser? This is the only one that works from al the given anwsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP has stated in comments, the expected input is in `99 string`

This can be represented in regex as 2 capture groups..

The first -> `\d\d`  2 numbers..
And the second -> `.*`  anything else..

You can then combine this with capture groups..

So the final regex would be `/(\d\d) (.*)/`

If the numbers could be other than just 2 digits long, you might want `\d+` instead.

Here is a working example of `99 string`

```js
console.log("59 Samuël 1 en 2".match(/(\d\d) (.*)/).slice(1));
```

If the numbers could be single, or even 3 numbers this might be better.

```js
console.log("59 Samuël 1 en 2".match(/(\d+) (.*)/).slice(1));
console.log("159 Samuël 1 en 2".match(/(\d+) (.*)/).slice(1));
console.log("9 Samuël 1 en 2".match(/(\d+) (.*)/).slice(1));
```

Comment: Yes, exacly. I changed `.match(/(\d\d) (.*)/)` into `.match(/(\d+) (.*)/)` aswell, in my code. And it works as a charme. Thanks, I was breaking my head into solving this :)

Comment: YES! I needed to retrieve the first string of numbers (before any non-numeric character) in my string. `console.log("59654567,456123".match(/(\d+)/).slice(1)); \\59654567` was great

Answer (score 0):

I think using a capturing group with a ".+" to include everything after should work.

```js
var string = '59343 Samuël 1 en 2';
console.log(string.split(/\d+(.+)/)[1].replace(' ', ''));
```

Comment: The output is a string, I want the output to be an array, eg `['59343', 'Samuël 1 en 2']`

Comment: Oh, shoot sorry I read that too fast. Looks like you got an answer though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing parantheses, then filter out the empty matches

```js
const str = '50 Samuël 1 en 2';
console.log(str.split(/(\d+)(.+)/).filter(e => e));
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes care of it as long as you can count on there being a space after the first series of digits. It's not pretty, but it should be very clear, so improving its efficiency is an option if you prefer.

(Note that splitting on digits removes the digits, which isn't what you're actually looking for according to your expected output.)

```
var str = '59 Samuël 1 en 2';
var arr = str.split(" ");
let i = 0, firstIntPosInArr = -1;
for(; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i])){
        firstIntPosInArr = i;
        console.log(`${i}: ${arr[i]}`);
        break; 
    }
}

console.log(firstIntPosInArr);

let firstPart = [], secondPart = [], output = [];
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(i <= firstIntPosInArr){ firstPart.push(arr[i]); }
    else secondPart.push(arr[i]);
}

console.log("1:" + firstPart);
console.log("2:" + secondPart);

output.push(firstPart.join(' '));
output.push(secondPart.join(' '));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're not tied to using `split` only you could combine it with slice and join to achieve the desired result.

```
[
  string.split(/(\d+)/)[0],
  string.split(/(\d+)/).slice(1).join(' ')
]
```

Another alternative would be to use this RegExp which will only match the first number, but this will also need to be combined with `filter` as it creates a match for `''` as the first entry in the output array.

```
string.split(/^(\d*) /).filter(Boolean);
```

**EDIT:** **Best final solution:**

To solve with a single RegExp and `split` you can use the following:

```
string.split(/[^\d](.*\d*)$/, 2);
```

This RegExp will split on (and capture) the whole string from the last digit to before the first digit, ie *"Samuël 1 en 2"*. This method still produces an excess empty string at the end of the `split` array which is why the limiter is necessary.